# Is there any way to verify that a person owns/controls a particular RSS feed?

Tags: rss, feed, verify, ownership, authentication

I have a project where I want to be able to monitor user's RSS feeds from their blogs or other content generating sources, but I need to somehow verify that they actually own the RSS feed and aren't just pointing to someone else's blog or content. Is there a way to do this on the feed itself, like a `<meta>` section in the feed? My other thought is to force the person to verify ownership of the domain or site that hosts the feed, instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closest thing to a standard way of handling this that I know of is to use a `<link>` with `rel="me"`. Google Buzz uses this approach. Basically, you have something like this in the feed:

```
<link rel="me" type="text/html" href="http://www.google.com/profiles/username"/>
```

This indicates that the feed belongs to the same person as `http://www.google.com/profiles/username`. You can have multiple `link` elements with the same `rel`, so you can have links to multiple user profiles (typically profiles of the same person on multiple services) on the same feed.

An alternative approach is to require that the user place a random magic token in the body of their feed. This token only needs to exist for a single fetch, so the user can remove it once your service has determined that they own the feed. I think this approach may have been used by Feedburner. The problem with this approach is that it is open to abuse by feeds of aggregate user generated content. For example, a malicious user could claim to own a comments feed or a wiki changelog feed pretty easily. Requireing that the magic token be in the feed description rather than in an item might be a way to solve this problem, though it may cause trouble for users that don't have low-level control over their feed. (eg: users of certain content management systems or blogging tools) The `rel=me` approach has this problem too, but at least it's standard-ish, so hopefully the creators of said CMS/blogging tools can be convinced into adding support for `rel=me`.

A third approach is to require that the user prove that they own the domain, as you mentioned. This has some issues, as a user may own only a directory tree on a domain or a subdomain. You don't want to assume ownership of an entire domain just because a user can edit a file on some subdirectoy or subdomain. The "directory" and host of the "proof" URL should probably be an ancestor of the feed URL. For example, if I can control `example.com/foo/proof.txt` that does not mean I own `example.com/quux/zarf.xml`. If I can control `example.com/quux/proof.txt`, or `example.com/proof.txt` that's probably good enough, though.